# Como ordenar correctamente imágenes en vista Mobile

Tags: html, css, css3

Estoy creando un sitio web donde debo agregar algunas imágenes, las imágenes para la vista desde el escritorio se visualizan correctamente y se visualizan así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de visualizar desde mobile, la correcta posición de las imágenes para la vista mobile debería ser la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que estoy utilizando para la visualización de las imágenes en html es el siguiente:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="logoImage">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12" style="display:flex; justify-content:center">
                <img alt="image" src="../content/image1.png" width="240" height="250">
                <img alt="image" src="../content/image2.png" width="260" height="250">
                <img alt="image" src="../content/image3.png" width="250" height="250">

            </div>
            <div class="row" style="width:100%;">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12" style="display:flex; justify-content:center">
                    <img alt="image" src="../content/image4.png" width="400" height="240">
                    <img alt="image" src="../content/image5.png" width="400" height="100" style="margin-top: 70px; margin-left: 40px;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Quisiera saber si hay alguna modificación que deba realizar en mi código o agregar algo desde el css, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Deberias de usar bootstrap v4, espero que esto te ayude

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="logoImage row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" style="margin-bottom: 15px; text-align: center">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x300/02d" alt="placeholder" style="max-width: 100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" style="margin-bottom: 15px; text-align: center">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x300/02d" alt="placeholder" style="max-width: 100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" style="margin-bottom: 15px; text-align: center">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x300/02d" alt="placeholder" style="max-width: 100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" style="margin-bottom: 15px; text-align: center">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x300/02d" alt="placeholder" style="max-width: 100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" style="margin-bottom: 15px; text-align: center">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x300/02d" alt="placeholder" style="max-width: 100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" style="margin-bottom: 15px; text-align: center">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x300/02d" alt="placeholder" style="max-width: 100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" style="margin-bottom: 15px; text-align: center">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x300/02d" alt="placeholder" style="max-width: 100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" style="margin-bottom: 15px; text-align: center">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x300/02d" alt="placeholder" style="max-width: 100%">
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, tendrás una posible solución en Bootstrap 3.x ? Aun no adapto el desarrollo a Bootstrap 4

Comment: Ajuste la respuesta con bootstrap 3, espero y te ayude

Comment: Gracias por el ajuste, consideras agregar cada imagen en un div ?

Comment: Puedes usarla de esa manera o puedes hacer uso del flexbox, aqui te dejo un ejemplo: https://codepen.io/epsilonxaos/pen/ExQqpVr